# How to calculate the mean of a different timeframe using live data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am fighting with resampling and the mean calculation of a timeseries.
My example is working correctly *BUT* it does not look optimized to me, for big dataframes it will be slow.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'open': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'low': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
    'high': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    'close': [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5]
}, index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00:00', freq='T', periods=10))

df
                     open  low  high  close
2018-01-01 00:00:00     1  0.1    10    1.5
2018-01-01 00:01:00     2  0.2    20    2.5
2018-01-01 00:02:00     3  0.3    30    3.5
2018-01-01 00:03:00     4  0.4    40    4.5
2018-01-01 00:04:00     5  0.5    50    5.5
2018-01-01 00:05:00     6  0.6    60    6.5
2018-01-01 00:06:00     7  0.7    70    7.5
2018-01-01 00:07:00     8  0.8    80    8.5
2018-01-01 00:08:00     9  0.9    90    9.5
2018-01-01 00:09:00    10  1.0   100   10.5
```

then i resample to 5T at each index of `df` because i need to calculate the mean until that index on an higher frequency (5T) and put the value of the mean() in the main dataframe `df`.

To *simulate* what i need to do please look at the complete resampling code:

```
ohlc = {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last'}
sma = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    sma.append(df.loc['2018-01-01 00:00:00':row.Index].resample('5T', closed='left', label='left').apply(ohlc)['close'].rolling(2).mean().tail(1)[0])

df['5t_sma'] = sma
```

It work perfectly. The result is:

```
df
                     open  low  high  close  5t_sma
2018-01-01 00:00:00     1  0.1    10    1.5     NaN
2018-01-01 00:01:00     2  0.2    20    2.5     NaN
2018-01-01 00:02:00     3  0.3    30    3.5     NaN
2018-01-01 00:03:00     4  0.4    40    4.5     NaN
2018-01-01 00:04:00     5  0.5    50    5.5     NaN
2018-01-01 00:05:00     6  0.6    60    6.5     6.0
2018-01-01 00:06:00     7  0.7    70    7.5     6.5
2018-01-01 00:07:00     8  0.8    80    8.5     7.0
2018-01-01 00:08:00     9  0.9    90    9.5     7.5
2018-01-01 00:09:00    10  1.0   100   10.5     8.0
```

The values are correct but the problems are:

1. I do resampling at every index, sounds too heavy.
2. I know that i can calculate the mean at every 5minutes index without passing the range `loc[start:end]` the problem is that it assumes that i want to analyze the entire dataframe at once, 
   i cannot do that, i must treat it like "live data". At every minute i get an update with 1 minute data (open, low, high, close) and then i need to calculate the mean on the higher timeframe.

Can i get the same result without stressing too much pandas (0.23.4)? :)

Comment: FWIW, 5t simple moving average is just a ``rolling(5).mean()``. I have no idea why you're doing cumulative mean from midnight...